# Sentencia MySQL/MariaDB recursiva, Devolver vacío si hijos no cumplen condición

Tags: mysql, mariadb, recursión, cte

Tengo tablas de este estilo en la base de datos:

Category

| id_category | id_parent | level_depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 |
| 21 | 2 | 2 |
| 22 | 2 | 2 |
| 30 | 22 | 3 |

Category_product

| id_category | id_product |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 201 |
| 2 | 202 |
| 20 | 202 |
| 20 | 203 |
| 20 | 204 |

Tengo esta sentencia que borra las categorías que no tienen productos.

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'category SET `active` = 0 WHERE `id_category` NOT IN(SELECT `id_category` FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product)');
```

Pero esto no me sirve porque no quiero borrar categorías padre si las categorías hijos si tienen productos.
**Me gustaría obtener las categorías que no tienen productos donde todos sus hijos tampoco tengan productos.**

He estado probando con sentencias Select recursivas, pero necesitaría que NO devolviera nada en caso de que algún hijo tenga producto. **Esta consulta no es correcta** porque me devuelve todas las categorías que no tiene ningún producto y además todos los hijos que no tienen producto.

```
with recursive decendents as (
-- Categoria que no tiene Productos
Select c.id_category
FROM category c
WHERE c.id_category NOT IN(SELECT id_category 
                            FROM category_product)
union all
    -- Categorias hijo
    SELECT c.id_category
    FROM category c, decendents d
    WHERE c.id_parent = d.id_category AND c.id_category NOT IN(SELECT id_category 
                                                                FROM category_product)
)                                               
SELECT id_category From decendents
```

Alguna idea de como puedo conseguir esto? ya sea con consulta recursiva o no.

Gracias.

Comment: Intente algo como [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=387223320c67a789a7bfef9d7969cc7f).

Answer (score 0):

Preferiblemente me decantaría por la opción **iterativa**, pues consume menos memoria que la recursiva evitando así el desbordamiento de la pila o **stackoverflow** ;)

En primer lugar vamos a añadirle una nueva columna a tu dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
  id_category int,
  id_parent int,
  level_depth int
  );
CREATE TABLE category_product(
  id_category int,
  id_product int
  );
INSERT INTO category (id_category, id_parent, level_depth) VALUES
  (1,0,0),
  (2,1,1),
  (20,2,2),
  (21,2,2),
  (22,2,2),
  (30,22,3);
INSERT INTO category_product (id_category, id_product) VALUES
  (2,200),
  (2,201),
  (2,202),
  (20,202),
  (20,203),
  (20,204);
```

Será un simple campo calculado, pero simplificará el borrado posterior:

```
ALTER TABLE category ADD n_products int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

UPDATE category JOIN (
    SELECT id_category,COUNT(*) n
      FROM category_product
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id_category)
  set n_products=n;
```

Obteniendo algo así para tus datos de muestra:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id_category | id_parent | level_depth | n_products |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|           1 |         0 |           0 |          0 |
|           2 |         1 |           1 |          3 |
|          20 |         2 |           2 |          3 |
|          21 |         2 |           2 |          0 |
|          22 |         2 |           2 |          0 |
|          30 |        22 |           3 |          0 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Ahora únicamente tendremos que prescindir de aquellos registros que no tengan ni productos ni hijos. Es decir, que `n_products=0` y que no estén en la lista de padres:

```
DELETE FROM category
  WHERE n_products=0
  AND id_category NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_parent
      FROM category
  );
```

Este borrado habrá que repetirlo hasta que el número de filas borradas sea cero:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category
  WHERE n_products=0
  AND id_category NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_parent
      FROM category
  );
```

En tu caso, un par de veces. Una vez terminado, tu tabla `category` debería quedar así:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id_category | id_parent | level_depth | n_products |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|           1 |         0 |           0 |          0 |
|           2 |         1 |           1 |          3 |
|          20 |         2 |           2 |          3 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

En donde la categoría `1` no se elimina porque, aunque no tenga productos, tiene hijos y hasta nietos.

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.